# Trans vs. cis, or Z vs. E

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

I am new to organic chemistry and am confused regarding the following question:

Does the geometrical isomerism of 3-methyl-2-heptene fall into the category of trans vs. cis, or the category of Z vs. E? And what is the rule that determines whether it falls into the first or the second category?

My textbook is not clear on this.

Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you! The thing is that it says somewhere in my notes that cis vs. trans requires there to be two H atoms, obviously on opposite sides of the double bond. This is of course not the case here. Yet I cannot find any external support for this "rule" that miraculously made it into my notes…

Comment: That rule in this context is correct. The corresponding wording in the current IUPAC recommendations is: "… 'cis' and 'trans' are used … only to describe double bonds having to hydrogen atoms, one on each carbon atom. …"

Answer (score -1):

*(Z)* is the same like *cis*

*(E)* is the same like *trans*

BUT *cis* and *trans* is usually only for double bonds with 2 different substituents. Confusion can arise when, for instance, you have 2-halobut-2-enes, because some take the highest priority when determining if this is *cis* or *trans* whereas others may take the identical groups.

You can use *(Z)* and *(E)* for more than 2 substituents, for those with higher priority. Like in your example.

In general it is better to use *(Z)* and *(E)* nomenclature to avoid these ambiguities.